# How to quantize surface normals

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, computer-vision, quantization

I am trying to quantize surface normals into let's say 8 bins.

For example, when computing features like [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)  to quantize 2D gradients `[x,y]` into 8 bins we just take the angle with the y plane i.e. `arctan(y/x)` which will give us an angle between 0-360.

My question is, given a 3D direction `[x,y,z]`, a surface normal in this case, how can we histogram it in a similar way? Do we just project onto one plane and use that angle i.e. the dot product of `[x,y,z]` and `[0,1,0]` for example?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I also read a [paper](http://ar.in.tum.de/pub/hinterstoisser2011linemod/hinterstoisser2011linemod.pdf) recently where they quantized surface normals by measuring angles between normal and precomputed vectors that which are arranged around a right circular cone shape. I have added a link to this paper in the question (section 3.3.2 last paragraph), is this an effective approach? And if so, how do we compute these vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quantizing a continuous topological space corresponds to partitioning it and assigning labels to each partition. The straightforward standard approach for this scenario (quantizing normals) is as follows.

1. Choose your favorite uniform polyhedron:

   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron (4 faces)
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube (6 faces)
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron (8 faces)
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron (12 faces)
   - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron (20 faces)
   - In general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol
2. Develop a mapping function from a normal on the unit sphere to the face of your chosen polyhedron that the normal intersects.

   - I would advise doing an argmax across polyhedron faces, taking the dot product of your normal and each polyhedron face normal. The one that gives the highest dot product is the face your normal should be binned into.
3. Use the face normal for each polyhedron face as the label for that face.

Prefer this approach to the approach suggested by others of mapping to spherical coordinates and then binning those.  That approach suffers from too much sensitivity near the poles of the sphere.

## Edit

In the paper you added to your question, the same idea is being used.  There, however, the normals are restricted to a hemisphere - the only surfaces directly visible in an image have surface normals no more than 90 degrees away from the vector from the surface to the viewpoint.

The paper wants to quantize these surface normals into 8 values, represented by 8-bit integers with exactly one bit set to 1 and the rest set to 0. The 8 precomputed normals are computed as:

n<sup>t</sup><sub>x</sub> = cos(a)*cos(t)

n<sup>t</sup><sub>y</sub> = cos(a)*sin(t)

n<sup>t</sup><sub>z</sub> = sin(a)

where a = pi/4 and t = 0, pi/4, 2*pi/4, 3*pi/4, ..., 7*pi/4.

Notice

[cos(a)*cos(t)]<sup>2</sup> + [cos(a)*sin(t)]<sup>2</sup> + [sin(a)]<sup>2</sup> = cos<sup>2</sup>(a)[cos<sup>2</sup>(t) + sin<sup>2</sup>(t)] + sin<sup>2</sup>(a) = cos<sup>2</sup>(a) + sin<sup>2</sup>(a) = 1

Comment: Thanks Timothy, this sounds like a good approach. I also read a paper recently where they quantized surface normals by measuring angles between normal and precomputed vectors that which are arranged around a right circular cone shape. I have added a link to this paper in the question (section 3.3.2 last paragraph), is this similar to what you're saying? Thanks

Comment: Very similar idea in that paper.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it is correct, but would very much appreciate if you would be able to explain how the vectors described in that paper are precomputed

Comment: @Aly What is the underlying task you're trying to accomplish? I'll try to tailor the answer to your scenario, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I am actually trying to reproduce the work in that paper, so am trying to quantize surface normals into an 8-bit integer by binning it into 8 bins.

Comment: @Aly I edited the answer to include how to compute the surface normals. You could choose any fixed value between 0 and pi/2 for a - I just chose pi/4 because that should be close, but you can play with the value.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how they calculate the vector from the surface to the viewpoint? Or should this perhaps be a separate question...

Comment: Or do we assume viewpoint is at origin (0,0,0) and use the camera intrinsics to calculate the 3D vector of a pixel (we know depth) and then the vector is simply the vector from that point to (0,0,0)?

Comment: The normals are already with respect to screen space.  Don't worry about any camera model.

Answer (score 1):

> given a 3D direction [x,y,z], a surface normal in this case, how can
>   we histogram it in a similar way?

In the first case you quantize the polar orientation `theta` of the gradients. Now you need to quantize the spherical orientations `theta` and `phi` in a 2D histogram.

> Do we just project onto one plane and use that angle

The binning of the sphere determines how you summarize the information to build a compact yet descriptive histogram.

Projecting the normal is not a good idea, if `theta` is more important than `phi`, just use more bins for `theta`

**EDIT**

Timothy Shields points in his comment and his answer that a regular binning of `theta` and `phi` won't produce a regular binning over the sphere as the bins will be bunched toward the poles.

His answer gives a solution. Alternatively, the non-regular binning described here can be *hacked* as follows:

`Phi` is quantized regularly in `[0,pi]`. For `theta` rather than quantizing the range `[0,pi]`, the range `[-1,1]` is quantized instead;

For each quantized value `u` in `[-1,1]`, `theta` is computed as

```
theta = arcsin(sqrt(1 - u * u)) * sign(u)
```

`sign(u)` returns `-1` if `u` is negative, `1` otherwise.

The computed `theta` along with `phi` produce a regular quantization over the sphere.

To have an idea of the equation given above look at this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html). It describes the situation in the context of random sampling though.

**EDIT**

In the above hack Timothy Shields points out that only the area of the bins is considered. The valence of the vertices (point of intersection of neighboring bins) won't be regular because of the poles singularity.

A hack for the previous hack would be to remesh the bins into a regular [quadrilateral mesh](http://alice.loria.fr/publications/papers/2012/QuadStar_EG/STAR_quad_meshing.pdf) and keep the regular area.

A heuristic to optimize this problem with the global constraints of having the same valence and the area can be inspired from [Integer-Grid Maps Quad Meshing](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/David.Bommes/publications/IGM_preprint.pdf).

With the two hacks, this answer is too *hacky* and a little out of context as opposed to Timothy Shields answer.

Comment: This approach suffers because of the extra sensitivity near the singularities (poles).

Comment: This updated answer still has issues.  Your approach is the one typically taken for randomly uniformly sampling the surface of a sphere.  But that just means the regions will have equal area.  The shapes will be slivers that all meet at the point at the pole.

Comment: Thanks Timothy for pointing out my wrong assumptions. I'll clarify!

Answer (score 0):

A 3-dimensional normal cannot be quantized into a 1-D array as easily as for a 2-D normal (e.g., using arctan). I would recommend histogramming it into a 2-d space with a polar angle and an azimuth angle. For example, use [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) where the r (radius) value is always 1.0 (since your surface normal is normalized, length 1.0). In this case, you can throw away the r-value and just use polar angle θ (theta), and azimuthal angle φ (phi) to quantize the 3D normal.

Comment: This approach suffers because of the extra sensitivity near the singularities (poles).